# Open HTML file in browser in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, file

My applicattion is WPF:
I want to open the local file help.html of my project in the default browser.
I have created a button Help, in the event I want to open this .html.

I have some problems with the path...
Thanks.

Comment: Surely you can see that *'I have some problems with the path'* is not enough for anyone to be able to give you a meaningful answer?

Comment: @David make your question clear

Comment: where is the `help.html` file against application folder?

Comment: By the way; do you ever do a follow up to the answers and comments left at your questions? It would be helpful if you let us know which answers were helping you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can open any file with your default program using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method.

But before you have to open your file, you must be included in the application folder for this, you can click right on the file **go -> properties** and the properties box, select `Copy if newer` on the property `Copy to Output Directory`.

Put the below code in your button click event:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("help.html");
```

Comment: with this code, the program 
throws an exception: The system can not find the file specified. The html file is in the project folder.

Comment: the file `help.html` is within any folder?

Comment: help.html and MainWindow.xaml is in root directory

Answer (score 5):

Use below code in  `button_Click`  event

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("your HTML File Path");
```